# How do I compare the ID of the new members with the ones in the database?

Tags: discord, discord.js, quick.db

I am trying to make a jail command when the members who has this role leave the server and rejoin again the role stay with them ,i want when new members enter the server to compare their ID with the one in the database, if is it true it gives a role again. my code:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd",async (member)=>{
     let injail = await db.fetch(`ja_${member.guild.id}`)
     let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(n => n.name === 'Jail');
     if(member.guild.id = injail){
    member.roles.remove(user.roles.cache)
    member.roles.add(role)
     }
  });

client.on('message', msg => {
if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'jail')){
    if(!owners.includes(msg.author.id)) return msg.channel.send("**You Dont Have Perms **")
    if(!msg.channel.guild) return;
    var logChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === logID)//LOG
   
  let jailRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(n => n.name === 'Jail');
  let user = msg.mentions.members.first() //You can change this to an ID
  let args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
 
  if(!args[0]) return msg.channel.send('**:x: Please Mention A User**')
  if(user.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return msg.channel.send("**Im NOT Allowed To Do This **")
  
  let there = db.get(`jl_${msg.guild.id}_${user}`, user.id)
  if (there) return msg.channel.send('**This User AlREADY In Jail ⛔**')
 
  msg.channel.send(`**ADDED ${user} to the Jail! ✅**`)
  db.set(`jl_${msg.guild.id}_${user}`, user.id)
  user.roles.remove(user.roles.cache)
  user.roles.add(jailRole)
 
   
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Jail System')
        .setAuthor(msg.author.tag,msg.author.avatarURL({dynamic:true}))
        .addField("Status",`JOINED THE JAIL `)
        .addField("User",`<@${user.id}> (ID: ${user.id})`)
        .addField("By",`<@${msg.author.id}> (ID: ${msg.author.id})`)
        .setTimestamp()
      logChannel.send(embed)
    }
   
});
```

Comment: please add the code that relate and interact with database here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever people gets "jail" role, save "yes" to database.
and check condition as you did above.

here I'll give sample code:

```js
// when people gets jail role, add following code:
db.set(`ja_${msg.guild.id}_${user}`, "yes") // or you can simply use boolean operator

// when guildMemberAdd event triggers check condition:
let condition = db.fech(`ja_${member.guild.id}_${member.user.id}`)

if(condition === "yes"){
    // write code to add "jail" role to the member
}
else{
    // your other code
}
```

Also don't forget to set "no" in the database whenever you remove jail role from member.